# Interacting with root AppComponent - Angular

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-components

I am trying to implement functionality where in a component `SettingsComponent` a user presses a button and the banner in the root `AppComponent` will change.

```
customBanner():void{
  this.changeBanner = true;
}
```

The above function is called when a user presses a button in `SettingsComponent`. The banner for the app is in the root `AppComponent`:

```
<div *ngIf ="!changeBanner">
    <h2 class="main-header"><img src = "../../../assets/images/banner.jpg" style="max-height:40px"></h2>
</div>
<div *ngIf ="changeBanner">
    <h2>Custom Banner</h2>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`changeBanner` is a variable of `AppComponent`. I'm trying to get it where when the user presses the button in `SettingsComponent` the variable `changeBanner` in `AppComponent` will be changed.

Right now I am trying this:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 changeBanner = false; 
 @ViewChild(SettingsComponent)
 private settings:SettingsComponent; 

 ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.changeBanner = this.settings.changeBanner; 
 }
}
```

Right even before I press anything on the `settings` page I get an error

> Cannot read property 'changeBanner' of undefined

talking about the `this.settings.changeBanner`.

If I press a button nothing happens. I'm not sure If I'm going about this the right way at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the topic is communication between different components. Usually, when a child component wants to communicate with the parent, you would use event binding through the `@Output` property.

But in your case the banner property seems to be shared state between many components. In this case, it is better to create a service, that holds that state. All the components, that are supposed to change the banner, get an instance of this BannerService. The BannerService has an Observable, that emits changes, when the banner changes. The AppComponent can then subscribe to that Observable and change the banner accordingly.

Another alternative for managing shared state is ngrx, which is great but has a rather steep learning curve.

Comment: Will the AppComponent be able to detect the change, even though it's only initialized once? I tried using a service and put it in `ngOnInit` but I think my problem was that it never updated.

Comment: Yes, that is what the Observable is for. You only subscribe to it once, but it will get notified every time a change is emitted and can then run your customBanner method

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: It works. Now my main issue, is that on a refresh, what I got back from the observable doesn't persist.

Comment: Well, that's a completely different topic. If you want persistance in your app, you either have to store the state locally in the browser e.g. by using LocalStorage or store it on your server.

Answer (score 1):

The instance of SettingsComponent would need to be a direct child of AppComponent, i.e. there needs to be a `<my-settings></my-settings>` or the like in AppComponent's view. Otherwise this cannot work.

That aside, you should either use a template binding or an intermediate service to move data from one component to another.

Comment: I see so the `router-outlet` does not imply a child-parent relationship?

Comment: exactly. I'd prefer global `SettingsService` for this. Check my edit. (scratch that, check Jun Kang's answer)

Comment: Jun Kang's. My bad

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the @ViewChild(SettingsComponent) in your AppComponent.

make a function in AppComponent called `bannerChanged(){ this.changeBanner = !this.changeBanner;}`

in your html for app component do this:

```
<app-settings  (bannerChanged)="bannerChanged($event)"></app-settings>
```

then in your SettingsComponent have this:

```
@Output() bannerChanged = new EventEmitter<void>();
...
changeBanner(){
   this.bannerChanged.emit();
}
```

the changeBanner function is to be called when your button is pressed

Comment: The problem with this if I understand this correctly, is that now the whole `app-settings` page is rendered in `app-component`.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want that then make a SettingsReducer called 'settings' and subscribe to changes on it, and when the button is pressed in SettingsComponent dispatch the change:

```
//in app.module.ts
StoreModule.forRoot({settings: SettingsReducer})
//in SettingsReducer
export function SettignsReducer(state: SettingStore = SettingsState, { type, payload}){
   switch (type) {
      case ('SETTINGS_CHANGED'):
         return (Object.assign({}, state, { settingValue: payload });
   }
}

//in appComponent
constructor(private store: Store<SettingStore>){
   this.store.select('settings').subscribe(value => this.changeBanner = value['settingValue'];);
}

//in SettingsComponent
buttonClicked(){
   let value = !this.currentValue;
   this.store.dispatch({type: 'SETTINGS_CHANGED', payload: value});
}
```